# Unable to deploy a Remix App to Azure App service using Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, remix.run

I have a remix app built using the Remix App Server template. I am trying to build it using Azure App Service. The issue is that "build" command generates a .cache folder and there are issues with permissioning only while copying that. The goal is to run "npm run start" after the build is deployed.

This is my yml.

```
# Node.js Express Web App to Linux on Azure
# Build a Node.js Express app and deploy it to Azure as a Linux web app.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- development

variables:

  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: <subscription_id>

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'remix'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'remix-app'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  # PNPM Cache Location
  pnpm_config_cache: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.pnpm-store

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '18.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - task: Cache@2
      inputs:
        key: 'pnpm | "$(Agent.OS)" | pnpm-lock.yaml'
        path: $(pnpm_config_cache)
      displayName: Cache pnpm

    - script: |
        corepack enable
        corepack prepare pnpm@latest-8 --activate
        pnpm config set store-dir $(pnpm_config_cache)
      displayName: "Setup pnpm"

    - script: |
        pnpm install
        pnpm run build
      displayName: 'pnpm install, build'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: remix'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              appName: $(webAppName)
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|18'
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              startUpCommand: 'npm run start'
```

This is the error I get.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned this [**repository**](https://github.com/aaronpowell/azure-remix-stack) I used Node.js React app with Azure Web app as remix works better with react.

[image]

***Select your Web app and run the yaml pipeline:-***

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:

 
  azureSubscription: 'azuresubscription-id'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'siliconwebapp1'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'siliconwebapp1'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: siliconwebapp1'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              WebAppName: $(webAppName)
              packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              RuntimeStack: 'NODE|10.10'
              StartupCommand: 'npm run start'
              ScriptType: 'Inline Script'
              InlineScript: |
                npm install
                npm run build --if-present
```

Above method does not include any cache task or copy files. But in your task you can add:-

```yaml
- script: | 
    pnpm install 
    npm run build
    rm -rf .cache 
 displayName: 'pnpm install, build, and delete .cache folder'
```

To remove the cache files before archive task.

[image]

If you face any issues related to the dependencies make sure you update those packages via npm commands. First run the code locally with `npm run setup` and `npm run dev` command. If the app runs locally, Push the code in your Azure DevOps pipeline and run again.